# masking operation in python and numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am multiplying two n-d arrays using some set of indices that I have obtained using numpy mesh grid. So, I have two n-d arrays called current and previous and I have a set if indices p and q and I have something as follows:

```
time_lag = numpy.sum(current[p] * previous[q])
```

Now, I have a another n-d array filled with only 0s and 1s and what I want to do is make sure this multiplication only happens in the indices where this mask is set to 1. So, currently I am just doing:

```
time_lag = numpy.sum(current[p] * previous[q] * mask[p])
```

This ensures that it zeros out the regions I do not want and they do not contribute to the sum. I wonder if there is a better way to only selectively do the multiplication in those mask regions?

Comment: In what way *better*?

Comment: I was thinking perhaps this multiplication is less efficient. Also, this binds me to have this masking image only containing 0 and 1 and perhaps I would like it to be more flexible in the future.

Comment: If your code works, you might want to submit your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and be a bit more specific about what you want to achieve.  A trip through the documentation might help also.  Are these calcs performed while iterating?

Comment: Thanks for that. I did not know about that forum! So, the indices are generated using mesh grid, so all the computation with this one line. So, there is no loop involved. p and q are arrays of indices. Somehow the numpy documentation site seems to be down since yesterday as well!

Comment: @Luca could you please specify the shapes of `current, previous, p, q and mask`?